# Accessing a property defined in the class extension from a category, in Objective-C: is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, properties, objective-c-category, class-extensions

One of my classes `MyClass` is very big and I want to split it into several categories `MyClass(A)`, `MyClass(B)`, ... . My problem is that some of the methods of `MyClass+A` make use of a `@property` defined in the class extension `MyClass()`.

- Can I access it from the category, and if yes: how?
- If no, is there another way to proceed?

Comment: You effectively need a public way to get at this private `@property`...which means the `@property` needs to be public now.  Is there a problem moving that `@property` to `MyClass.h`?

Comment: Anything's possible in Objective-C, if you cheat enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I access it from the category, and if yes: how?

Yes. Either:

1. define the continuation category in a different .h file (xxx_Private.h) and include that into your implementation files
2. Or, redefine the method in a category interface at the top of the implementation file.

Option 1 is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the property in a private header or redefine it as already suggested. Also the following approaches may sometimes be applicable:

1. Use the ObjectiveC runtime: id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...). Care should be taken when using primitive types or structures.
2. Use key-value coding: [someObject setValue:aValue forKey:@"propertyName"];
3. Use performSelector: [someObject performSelector:@selector(setFoobar) . . . ], note that this will fire a warning under ARC
4. Use an NSInvocation

Key-value coding is quite common. The others would be more applicable in libraries and frameworks, though you could certainly use them if called for.